# Whyn StreamBuilder's hasData property does no set to True if Observable emmits an event?

Tags: flutter, observable, rxdart

I need to implement search and display results. I use Observables from RxDart.

```
abstract class SearchState {}
class SearchCompleted extends SearchState {}
class SearchEmpty extends SearchState {}

final _searchSubject = PublishSubject<String>();

Observable<SearchState> get result {
  return _searchSubject.switchMap((term) {
    return _search(term); // returns Observable<SearchCompleted>
  }).switchIfEmpty(Observable.just(SearchEmpty()));
}
```

Somewhere in StreamBuilder is use this **result** as source for **stream**. And at opening screen (no search) I expect that

```
snapshot.hasData = true
```

because my observable emmits SearchEmpty but I get *false*. What I did wrong? All that I need is just display some message if search result is empty.

UPD: After additional investigation of StreamBuilder, reading RxDart docs and systemationzation of information from *pskink* I came to conclution that I was mistaken. [switchIfEmpty()](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/switchIfEmpty.html) means that stream is switched to fallback only if original stream returns nothing (after placing value to *sink*). I need use [startWith()](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/startWith.html) which forces the observable to emmit required *start* value. So the correct code is

```
Observable<SearchState> get result {
  return _searchSubject.switchMap((term) {
    return _search(term); // returns Observable<SearchCompleted>
  }).startWith(SearchEmpty());
}
```

UPD2: At **first** build of widget StreamBuilder's `snapshop.hasData = false`, even using startWith() because `connectionStatus = ConnectionStatus.waiting` (i.e. when stream is preparing to receive data). To avoid this you **must** set value for [initialData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder/initialData.html) property. For example:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  initialData: SearchEmpty(),
  stream: result,
  builder: ...
)
```

Or you can return some widget while connection is in *waiting* status. For example:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: result,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // this allow to skip using `initialData`
    if (snapshot.connectionStatus == ConnectionStatus.waiting) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    // Process data
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data is SearchEmpty()) { return Text('no items');}
      if (snapshot.data is SearchCompleted()) { return ListView(...);}
    }
  }
),
```

Comment: what does `search(term)` return in case if nothing was found? an `Observable.empty()`?

Comment: What I noticed if I open page first time (term is empty) the code flow does not go inside switchMap(), i.e. Observable result is returned at once and hasData = false. Yes when _search() has no found records it returns SearchEmpty(). But the question is why result does not switched to fallback stream when it does not emmit anything at start.

Comment: try this and see the logs: `PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject();
    subject
        .switchMap((s) =>
            _search(s).switchIfEmpty(Observable.just('*** NOT FOUND ***')))
        .listen(print);` - test it with that hypothetical `_search()` method: `Observable<String> _search(String term) {
  return term.length < 8 ? Observable.just('[$term]') : Observable.empty();
}`

Comment: I have done so and I didn't see any output. But when I did so
`_searchSubject.add('test')`
I saw the _test_

This modification

`subject.switchMap((s) => _search(s)).switchIfEmpty(Observable.just('*** NOT FOUND ***')).listen(print);`
also does not give response.

Comment: As I mentioned in above comment I already did what you've suggested. Instead of using TextController I just directly send a value to stream. But (I repeat :)) the problem is when nothing is sent I don't see *** NOT FOUND*** in console. It looks like this event is not emmited when stream is empty. :(

Comment: why do you want "not found" if you did not type anything? or i am missing something? if not, try `Observable#startWith` maybe?

Comment: Why? Because...
_When the original observable emits no items, this operator subscribes to the given fallback stream and emits items from that observable instead._
[switchIfEmpty](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/switchIfEmpty.html)
**I want to send something if observable does not send anything.** Maybe I misunderstand the written doc?

Comment: startWith does not help. It **prepends** with _startValue_ only when I will send something to stream. And I don't need to send _empty string_ because it is forbidden (why I need to search empty string?) I need to send some **default** value when no search is executed yet or when I want to restore last search result when I closed then re-open the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193676/discussion-between-aleksei-timkov-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

I've just had something like that problem at the moment, I worked around it getting the DataSnapshot, which returns `null` if there's no key/value.

```
if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.snapshot.value != null) {
  return //your code
}
else if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.snapshot.value == null){
  return //no items found
}
else{
  return //your code
}
```

This way I could manage the StreamBuilder when it has no data.

This would work aswell:

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
  if(snapshot.data.snapshot.value == null){
    return //no data found
  }
  else{
    return //data
  }
}
```